# Scroll issue in fixed div (modal) using intro.js hints

Tags: javascript, jquery, intro.js

**EDIT**
The issue is *almost* fixed...

I found a quite ugly way to adjust the hint position on `scroll`. It work perfectly on a desktop screen.

But there is issues on mobile:

1. The scroll event tends to lag (at least on my Android Samsung Galaxy S3).
   This could be tolerable...
2. When an `input` is focussed, the mobile key pad messes the offset calculation.
   This is no-go.

**So if anyone has a better idea to fix this...**

You can try my *almost working* solution using this [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/full/yMWjEv/).

Here is the "almost fix" code:
*(I use an array to store `lastScroll`, because I obviously want to use more than one hint.)*

```
// Position sub function
var lastScroll=[];
function fixHintPosition(container,hintNumber){

  if(typeof(lastScroll[hintNumber])=="undefined"){
    lastScroll[hintNumber]=0;
  }

  // Scrolled px
  var scroll = $(container).scrollTop();
  //console.log("Pixel scrolled: "+scroll);

  // Actual dot position
  var actualPos=parseInt($('a.introjs-hint').eq(hintNumber).css("top"));
  //console.log(actualPos);

  // New position
  var newPos=actualPos+(lastScroll[hintNumber]-scroll);
  $('a.introjs-hint').eq(hintNumber).css("top",newPos);

  // Last scroll memory
  lastScroll[hintNumber] = scroll;

  // If dot is out of the container
  var out=false;
  var containerOffset = parseInt(container.css("top"));

  if(newPos>containerOffset+container.height()){
    $('a.introjs-hint').eq(hintNumber).addClass("introjs-hidehint");
    out=true;
    console.log("Dot is below modal");
  }
  if(newPos<containerOffset){
    $('a.introjs-hint').eq(hintNumber).addClass("introjs-hidehint");
    out=true;
    console.log("Dot is above modal");
  }
  if(!out){
    $('a.introjs-hint').eq(hintNumber).removeClass("introjs-hidehint"); 
    console.log("Dot is shown");
  }
}
```

**====================== Original question**

---

**Hi SO friends.**

I'm asking something for the 5th time.
*(I gave 398 answers up to now, so please consider my question with care)*

**Issue is:**

I want to use [**intro.js**](http://introjs.com/) hints in a fixed position and scrollable modal.
Since intro.js marvelously handles everything by **adding the hint elements** to the body...
It works fine on a normal page.

But not in a modal...


**I see 2 options:**

1. Try to use the introjs.js `refresh()` function found looking at the .js file.
   *(not found  in documentation... And this is not working anyway)*
2. Manage to move these elements from body to the modal using a "patch script".

   **BUT** I have to say that my example is quite minimal as per [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) but complete.

    -- My modal loads Ajax content. --
   I'm hidding/showing/updating the hints without issue... And very easily (this plugin is magic!).

   This is working soooo great!!

   I already manage the FR/EN translation of theses «hints».
   **BUT now, please tell me there is simple a way to make them just *damn* scroll with the target element!**



   I haven't found anything in the [intro.js documentation](http://introjs.com/docs/).
   Can you help me a little?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  function addHints(){
    intro = introJs();
      intro.setOptions({
        hints: [
          {
            element: document.querySelector('#test'),
            hint: "This is not scrolling with the page",
            hintPosition: 'middle-right'
          }
        ]
      });
      
    intro.onhintsadded(function() {
        console.log('Hint loaded');
    });
    
    intro.addHints();
  }

  addHints();
  
  // This is not working... Sadly....
  $("#scrollable").on("scroll",function(){
    console.log("Scroll");
    introJs().refresh();
  });
  
});
```

```css
body{
  text-align:center;
  background-color:cyan;
}
#scrollable{
  position:fixed;
  top:10%;
  left:20%;
  width:60%;
  height:200px;
  border:1px solid grey;
  border-radius:20px 0 0 20px;
  background-color:#fefefe;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://www.bessetteweb.com/2017/js/intro/demo.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intro.js/2.5.0/introjs.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/intro.js/2.5.0/intro.js"></script>


<body>
<div id="scrollable">
  <h1>
    Issue with the «hint»<br>
    on scroll
  </h1>
  <br>
  <input type="text" id="test"><br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Please all... Hold on while *«stacksnippets.net’s server DNS address could not be found.»* is fixed. My snippet is working.

Comment: Here is a [**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/oZRjWq)

Comment: *«stacksnippets.net»* is fixed now...

Comment: I just added an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/usablica/intro.js/issues/699)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are expecting this kind of work around. Here is what I did:

**HTML(Same as yours)**

```
 <body>
  <div id="scrollable">
  <h1>
    Issue with the «hint»<br>
    on scroll
  </h1>
  <br>
 <input type="text" data-position="bottom-right-aligned" data-hintposition="top-middle" data-hint="Get it, use it."  id="test"/><br>

  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function addHints() {
    intro = introJs();
    intro.onhintsadded(function() {
      console.log('Hint loaded Bolo tarara');
    });

    intro.addHints();
  }

  addHints();

  //find top of yhe scrollable according to the window size at "PAGE LOAD"
  var position = $("#test").offset();
  var containerTop;
  containerTop = $("#scrollable").offset().top;
  $("#scrollable").on("scroll", function() {
    var t, T, l;

    var window = document.getElementById('scrollable');

    //get amount of px scrolled
    var scrollLeft = (window.pageXOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageXOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollLeft;
    var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop() + "px";
    console.log(scroll);

    t = parseInt(position.top) - parseInt(scroll);
    T = t + "px";
    l = position.left;
    console.log("kitta hua scroll" + t);

    $("div.introjs-hints").css("position", "relative");
    //scroll your hint with the scrollbar
    document.getElementsByClassName('introjs-hint')[0].style.top = T;
    console.log("div ki offset n badri ki dulhaniya" + $("a.introjs-hint").offset().top);

    if (t < containerTop) //for aesthetics 
    {
      $("div.introjs-hints").css("display", "none");
    } else {
      $("div.introjs-hints").css("display", "block");
    }

    introJs().refresh(); //from your code
  });
});
```

Please implement accordingly.Thanks!

Comment: Your answer gave me ideas... And made me work on it again. So +1. Still, there are issues left. Please check my update. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your views. It works perfectly on my desktop,I will check the same on mobile.